# Sending bunch of commands from txt file in Expect

Tags: scripting, expect

How to send bunch of commands to Cisco router from txt file like:

```
configure
class-map match-any popc_fiberpower004_booster_v4
 match access-group ipv4 bng_permit_v4
 match access-group ipv6 bng_permit_v6
end-class-map
policy-map popc_fiberpower004_booster_v4_in
 class popc_fiberpower004_booster_v4
  police rate 110 mbps
  set dscp 0
 class class-default
end-policy-map
```

And of course from Expect script via telnet.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: This question might be better asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should probably be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Note that [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) is an extension of [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), so you'll want to use some [Tcl commands](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm)

- `open`
- `while`
- `gets`

You might find the [Tcl tutorial](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) helpful, particularly the [File Access 101](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl24.html) section.